# radium package in React JS is not woking. This message is being displayed in the browser

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

This message is being shown by NPM.

```
 Html Webpack Plugin:
  Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\  ajeet\Desktop\myreact\node_modules\webpack\buildin\global.js':
  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ajeet\Desktop\myreact  \node_modules\webpack\buildin\global
```

.js'

Comment: Have your run `npm install`?

Comment: yes.  I did already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'C:\Users\ ajeet\Desktop\myreact\node_modules\webpack\buildin\global.js'

I notice there is a blank space in above , before the 'ajeet'.